# how do i create this pulse using the HP 8112A

Tags: generator, pulse

[image]

how do I generate this pulse using the HP 8112A

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the user manual?

Comment: And what is your 5 msec referenced to?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort whatsoever is shown.

Comment: (1) Read the manual. (2) Do what it says. (3) Duh!

Comment: amend your question soon or it ends in trash bin

Comment: are you guys giving me this answer becauase you guys dont know it yourself?

Comment: http://exodus.poly.edu/~kurt/manuals/manuals/HP%20Agilent/HP%208112A%20Operating%20&%20Programming%20Only.pdf

Comment: thats the manual and i did play with the unit myself. i don't know how to make the pulse 42 ns. i can get 5ms per pulse but how do i make the pulse 42 ns short.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan Yes, this is one of the reasons. Your request translates into "Please, read the manual for me and explain how to do stuff written there". And if you can't do something, it's a good indication to check the capability of the device.

Comment: sorry, i am new to this forum. i tried contacting HP for help but they are hard to get a hold of when it comes to an old product. I asked for help in the yahoo forum and they asked what model is my product. i just wanted to ask the question short and precise.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan You should read the site FAQ. Your question doesn't conform to the site's standard for a 'good question'. I'm sure if you put more context and effort into the question, you'll get better responses. But this site doesn't exist to give easy answers to lazy people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand if English and Engineering are not your 1st languages ( just ask my wife when I speak engineering talk)

Think of this as a really fancy digital watch with a few more simple buttons but similar cycling of options.

[image]

The HP abbreviations are explained below for the default output.

[image]

> ** The first obvious step is press  the button below (WID) for pulse width until lit.
> Note the Range buttons ^ v and choose ( ns ).
> Then choose value using [Vernier]. (as in calipers)**

Note to all: Although this site assumes a little engineering knowledge, and effort on a good question. ESL is effective series inductance to us, but English second language to others.

The best answer is limited by the quality and relevance of the question.

Comment: manual http://www.keysight.com/en/pd-1000001733%3Aepsg%3Apro-pn-8112A/50-mhz-pulse-generator?pm=PL&nid=-536902328.536881157&cc=CA&lc=eng

Comment: Thank you so much. you're image helps. I was reading the other user manual which didnt included the definition of WID "pulse width".

Comment: ok don't forget to send coffee and baklava

Comment: whats coffee and baklava?